# What is the difference between attributes.$set() and element.attr() in directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Suppose I have a directive with a link property. What is the practical difference between those two:

```
link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
          elm.attr('src', "http://...");
      });
```

and

```
link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
          attrs.$set('src', "http://...");
      });
```

Comment: angular can't listen to the first because it isn't being compiled. `$set` will update the compiled attributes object